# How to detect onTap gesture in widgets inside the InteractiveViewer?

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I have multiple widgets inside an interactive viewer and I want to detect if they are clicked. Below is how the code looks like:

```
InteractiveViewer(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => print('tap'),
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => print('tap'),
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

The GesutreDetector inside cannot detect the onTap gesture, is there any way to achieve this?

I tried using Listener but was not fruitful.